# break the game when all the every element already filled

Tags: python

im still learning pyhton. and i try to figure out, How can i break the game when the all i(every element) already filled.
example:

d u c k

You Win!

```
import random
player = input("\nnama player:")
print("Welcome to the GuesOrd game", player.title() + ".")
print("\nKategori: Hewan")
words = ["duck", "chicken", "bird", "platypus"]
word = random.choice(words)
guesses = "
chance = 10
while True:
    for i in word:
        if i in guesses:
            print(i, end=" ")
        else:
            print("_", end=" ")
    guess = input("\nyour guess(only input 1 aplhabet):")[0]
    if guess in word:
        guesses += guess
    elif guess not in word:
        chance -= 1
        print("wrong guess. Guess again!")
        print("you have " + str(chance) + " chance left!")
        if chance == 0:
            print("\nGame Over!")
            print("The Answer Is", word)
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways to kill a cat. But off the top of my head, I'd say use something like this whenever the user enters a correct letter:

```
if guess in word:
    guesses += guess
    
    if sorted(guesses) == sorted(word):
        print("\nYou've won!")
        print("Answer is", word)
        break
```

Comment: i have tried it, but met a problem when the "word" have the same alphabets.

Comment: Ok I get it now. The string `guesses` can have the correct word but in the wrong order, as in "dkuc" instead of "duck" right? Simply sort the two strings before comparing them. Try `if sorted(guesses) == sorted(word):`

Comment: that's work, you're awesome dude. thx bruh

Comment: Anytime. Don't forget to upvote and mark as answer if it helped